# Create a seperate UI for external users in jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have generated a jhipster app with Angular 7 as front end framework and generated many entities for CRUD.

Now I need new front end with branding, styling and  new views to incorporate business logic etc. Also I need to  keep all admin pages of CRUD and monitoring.

I have two options:

1. Customize the the default angular app and change css and generated code, add new components etc. ( I dont want to do that).
2. Create a new seperate UI for external user while keeping the default generated UI for business users with some minor customization. ( I think this is better).

**What I have tried**

I have generated a new angular module with angular client and imported in default generated app module. In this new module, I have created a new component and I am able to access it by adding a link in default navbar.

**What is my problem?**
Now I can create more components in a seperate angular module and keep the generated on as it is, my confusion is that:

1. In a long term, by increasing the complexity of front end, will my code be maintainable.
2. Is there any better way of creating seperate UI layer for extrnal (non business) users?

   3. How do I manage authorization? Depending upon the role I need to redirect user to either businees app ( generated by jhipster) or the one we are going to generate ( for non business users/ external users)

I would love to show the code but it working fine till now ( new angular module generated by ng cli)

app.module.ts

```
import { ExternaluiModule } from './externalui/externalui.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiAppRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-' }),
        NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
            // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
            alertAsToast: false,
            alertTimeout: 5000
        }),
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiSharedModule.forRoot(),
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiCoreModule,
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiHomeModule,
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiAccountModule,
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        Poc3JhipsterCustomizeUiEntityModule,
        ExternaluiModule
    ],
```

Regards.

Comment: End user app is so different (CSS, HTML, API, maybe authentication type) that I usually prefer to create a separate frontend using angular-cli and if there are common things I create an npm module

Comment: Hi, yes they are common things we want to reuse, for example angular services for CRUD. Can you pls explain a little about your approach of creating a npm module? If you have anu link or document to follow please share with me.

Comment: Nothing specific to JHipster. https://angular.io/cli/generate#library

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Gaël Marziou.